# How to change alignment of tab header, after changed the alignment of tab from top to left?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my app i used tab controls, in this i changed the alignment of tab control from default position(Top) to Left by changing alignment to left, from this i got vertical alignment of tab control. My question is after changed the alignment to left, the text of tab control is aligned from bottom to top, i need to change it from left to right. Please make it.